# Automation of End to end Test with Selenium (for web App) and Appium (For Mobile App Testing)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, appium, end-to-end, mobile-applications

We have this kind of end to end tests to automate :

Log in in Web application. Follow few steps there. Do something in Web app so that logged user in Mobile App gets notification.
In Mobile App perform few steps.
Check in Web app that the statuses are reflected correctly on the basis of what was done in Mobile App.
What we have currently : The test framework (uses Page Object Model) where we have automated quite a few Tests. But they are currently limited to Web app only. We use Selenium with C# for this.

My questions :-

Would it be a good idea/practice to extend the current framework in order to incorporate Applium (to support Mobile App Testing) ? please note that there is no end points currently through which we can mock Mobile App part. For that we may need to develop a new environment which would be quite expensive.

Are there any other open source tools apart from Appium which are good and can make our job easy considering end to end test described above (with Web app and Mobile App) ?

Any links, videos or other material which helped you to automate such scenario ? Of course I am googling myself too !

I would truly appreciate your experiences, suggestions and remarks on this.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the current framework to incorporate Appium for mobile automation would be your best bet. Basically now your framework would have to 2 webdriver objects, one for webapp (Selenium-based) and the other for mobile app (Appium based).
So your user interface testing for a scenario would work like (pseudo-code),

```
WebDriver webAppDriver = initializeWebDriver();
AppiumDriver mobileAppDriver = initializeMobileDriver();

openWebApp(webAppDriver);
doSomeWebAction(webAppDriver);

checkMobileNotification(mobileAppDriver); 
doSomeMobileAction(mobileAppDriver);

checkWebNotification(webAppDriver);
```